# Biguqery Row Number Perioding based on specific values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So i have a raw data like this.

```
| User_id | Month | Device
| 001     | 01    | A 
| 001     | 02    | A 
| 001     | 03    | B (Base)
| 001     | 04    | A
| 002     | 01    | C
| 002     | 02    | C
| 002     | 03    | B (Base)
| 002     | 04    | B (Base)
| 003     | 01    | A
| 003     | 02    | B (Base)
| 003     | 03    | A
| 003     | 04    | B (Base)
```

I want to create period that split by B (Base) Device. I thinking about using Row Number but breaks only if meet B or several B's.

The result i want will be like this

```
| User_id | Month | Device  | rn
| 001     | 01    | A       | 1
| 001     | 02    | A       | 1
| 001     | 03    | B (Base)| 2
| 001     | 04    | A       | 3 
| 002     | 01    | C       | 1
| 002     | 02    | C       | 1
| 002     | 03    | B (Base)| 2
| 002     | 04    | B (Base)| 2
| 003     | 01    | A       | 1
| 003     | 02    | B (Base)| 2
| 003     | 03    | A       | 3
| 003     | 04    | B (Base)| 4
```

Is there any way we can populate rn like that?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below query.

```sql
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag), COUNTIF(flag) OVER w + 1 AS rn FROM (
  SELECT *,
         (LAG(Device) OVER w <> 'B' AND Device = 'B') OR
         (LAG(Device) OVER w = 'B' AND Device <> 'B') AS flag
    FROM sample_table
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY User_id ORDER BY Month)
) WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY User_id ORDER BY Month)
ORDER BY User_id, Month;


+---------+-------+--------+----+
| User_id | Month | Device | rn |
+---------+-------+--------+----+
|     001 |    01 | A      |  1 |
|     001 |    02 | A      |  1 |
|     001 |    03 | B      |  2 |
|     001 |    04 | A      |  3 |
|     002 |    01 | C      |  1 |
|     002 |    02 | C      |  1 |
|     002 |    03 | B      |  2 |
|     002 |    04 | B      |  2 |
|     003 |    01 | A      |  1 |
|     003 |    02 | B      |  2 |
|     003 |    03 | A      |  3 |
|     003 |    04 | B      |  4 |
+---------+-------+--------+----+
```